# How to update the camera in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, camera

I am new to Three.js I am trying to build an application using Three.js and web sockets.

There would be 2 applications having the same 3d object and if at one end I rotate the 3d object it should be rotated at the other end. When the object rotates I am trying to catch the camera position and send it through a web socket and then re-render it with the captured positions at other end.

At one end I am sending `camera.position` and on the other end I am updating the camera position with

```
camera.position.set(x,y,z)
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

This works partially (only zoom in and zoom out are working fine and in sync. When I rotate it is not working properly)

What else do I need in order to update it to make it work in sync at both ends?

Thank in advance.